# Adding functions to single quote

Tags: php, mysql, string, syntax

Help me

How can I insert a function inside a single quote?

```
<php 

echo ' Hello world <?php function(); ?> ';
```

what's the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use single quotes then you would concatenate (`.`) the function:

```
echo ' Hello world ' . function();
```

Comment: Is that a kind any kind of php tag recursion? Because I guess there should be a `<?php ?>` tag for the `echo` before your function call :)

Comment: The copy pasta thng caught me without my coffeee this morning @Asur

Comment: You caught me too, I thought that was even possible... I was just curious, I wouldn't argue a golden badge, thanks for clearing it up :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancatenate it.

```
echo 'Hello '. yourFunction() . 'world !';
```